# XTS-AES Mode in C#

Tags: c#, .net, aes

Is it possible to use AES in XTC mode in C# (.net 3.5)? It doesn't seem to be in the CipherMode enumeration. I cannot seem to find any implementations of it on the web.

**EDIT:** Since I couldn't find a .net implementation,  I wrote one: https://bitbucket.org/garethl/xtssharp

Comment: You might have more luck if you search using the "official" name - XTS-AES - although I did a quick search and couldn't find any C# or .NET implementations either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have since written a C# implementation of XTS mode (using the built in AES cipher in .net), and released it under a BSD license. You can find it here: https://bitbucket.org/garethl/xtssharp

Answer (score 0):

Here is the  [link](http://gladman.plushost.co.uk/oldsite/AES/) to a site which gives a C code to [download](http://gladman.plushost.co.uk/oldsite/AES/aes-xts-vs2008-17-07-09.zip) which implements C and XTS. I did not test it. You can wrap C code to C#.